# awk or sed lines between same pattern including the first match

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, scripting

This is the text:

```
* Tue This is the first line

– info 1

– info 2

– info 3

* Wed This is not to be included
```

The output of this text should be this:

```
* Tue This is the first line

– info 1

– info 2

– info 3
```

NOTE: I have tried awk and sed but failed to come up with my output. The problem is that the START and END are the same ‘*’ (asterisk) and the first one should be included in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Save sample text to the variable:

```
$ SAMPLE=$(cat <<EOF
* Tue This is the first line

– info 1

– info 2

– info 3

* Wed This is not to be included
* Tue This is the first line

– info 1

– info 2

– info 3

* Wed This is not to be included
EOF
)
```

Use `awk` to process your `$SAMPLE`:

```
$ awk '{if($1~"\*"){if(p==1){p=0;next}else{p=1}}if(p==1){print $0}}' <<<"$SAMPLE"
* Tue This is the first line

– info 1

– info 2

– info 3

* Tue This is the first line

– info 1

– info 2

– info 3
```

***EDIT***

As suggested in the comments there's surprisingly elegant `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '/^\*/{p=!p};p' <<<"$SAMPLE"
* Tue This is the first line

– info 1

– info 2

– info 3

* Tue This is the first line

– info 1

– info 2

– info 3
```

How it works:

- `/^\*/{p=!p};` - this will alternate the value of `p` to `1` and `0`. It will become `1` when regex `/^\*/` is first found. The second time it's found, `p` will become `0` and so on.
- `p` - this is equivalent to `p{print}`. Since `print` is the default action in `awk`, it will always print when precondition evaluates to the `true` value, in this case when `p` becomes `1`.

Comment: I feel this can be simplified to `awk '/^\*/{p=!p} p'`

Comment: Thank you for this `awk` sugar, I updated my answer. Please correct my comment on *how it works* if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand this correctly. This script will remove everything from the line starting with the second `*` until the end of the buffer, producing your desired output from the example:

```
sed -n 'H;1h;$x;$s/\(\*[^*]*\)\n\*.*$/\1/p'
```

Explanation append all lines (`H`) to the hold buffer. For the last line exchange hold and pattern buffer (`$x`), so you have the whole file as one pattern. In this pattern the part to be kept is set in `\(\)` and kept (`\1`), while everything from the newline with `*` is deleted.

This fits your description, but if it doesn't fit all possible examples, you can modify the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'if ( m?^\*? ... m?^\*? ) { print if !// || !$a++ }'

sed -e '
   /^\*/!d
   :loop
       $q; N
   /\n\*/!bloop
   s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/;q
'

sed -e '
   /^\*/!d
   :loop
      n
   //!bloop
   Q
'
```